# Cp command android from assets folder

Tags: java, android, linux

i want to know if it's possible execute "cp" linux command to copy a file from assets folder of my app to /system/bin partition (obviously with root access).

```
        Utility.exec("cp <file:///android_asset/my_file> /system/bin");
```

This code is valid to copy also files from assets to system/bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean example, assuming root is acquired :

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try
{
    is = assetManager.open("my_file");
    os = new FileOutputStream("/system/bin/my_file");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    // copy the file content in bytes 
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Dealing with the exception, log or something
}
finally
{
    if (is != null) try { is.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
    if (os != null) try { os.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: This will not work, as **"root" does not apply to the process of an android app**, and it's quite difficult to get custom java code running in the type of stand alone process to which it could apply (if such a hack were available on the device).

Comment: Good to know. So it's not doable ?

Comment: If there's a root hack, it should be possible to acquire the data from the asset in the android app process and pipe it into a native executable such as `dd` invoked with a single argument such as "of=/system/bin/this_is_a_bad_idea".  Of course /system is usually mounted read-only, too.

Answer (score 1):

> This code is valid to copy also files from assets to system/bin?

No.

First, the Linux **`cp`** command does not use schemes, AFAIK. Leastways, it does not work on Ubuntu.

Second, the `file:///android_asset/` URL prefix is pretty much just for `WebView`.

Third, assets are not files on the Android device. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK file. The **`cp`** command works with files.

You are welcome to use `AssetManager` and Java file I/O code to copy an asset to a local file.